# app compile Flutter Build Debug Error in code

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting this issue while building the flutter project but earlier same project is working fine ,i can't able to understand the issue.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 3 1 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Crash report written to C:\Users\hp\Desktop\schoolbells\flutter_02.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       431.2s (!)
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this Error before.

Try adding

```
         multiDexEnabled true
```

to android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
     
        applicationId "com.your_app.your_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         //Add this Line
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main file is called main_prod, rename it to to "main.dart".
After that, execute this command:
"flutter clean", it should fix it.

Comment: Already used the flutter clean command but still getting same issue

Comment: this project is working fine earlier,and but now its not working ,I have not done any changes